# Clicking a spoofed message customised to receivers id from Android

Tags: account-security, spoofing

Last night my friend's Skype account(which he stopped using 3 years ago) sent all of his contacts a web spoofed message in the following format
`www.google.com/something/something/... id=` with the receivers ID appended.

When I view it from Android I just see this link. When my other friend clicked it he said he saw an ad page and whenever he tried to click back another add popped up but nothing seemed to be downloaded.

What is the worst thing that can happen? If the phone is infected will it infect the pc when it is connected via a usb cable? If the phone is infected, is converting back to the factory settings a solution?

When I view it from my pc the title of the link becomes:

> Hoe IK (some money) Verdiende in 26 Dagen Zonder Ook Maar en Dubbeltje Uit Te Geven.

Translation:

> How I earned (amount) in 26 days without spending a dime.